# Best Practice: Return Statements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, return

As a matter of best practice, should all Javascript functions have a **`return`** statement at function block level?

Thus for functions not returning any value (void),

```
function jsFunction() {
   /*
    * code
    */
   return;
}
```

Or for function which may have a setting or other type of non-retrieving/getting function, returning some indication of success or failure (not a lot of these do, and are in fact void).  I suppose a boolean return value would be sensible.

```
function jsFunction() {
   /*
    * code to set or perform series of operation
    */
   if (failure == true)
     return false;
   return true; // success
}
```

A return statement can also show that the code writer is consciously signifying that the function is complete and no code is missing.  Not sure what best practices dictates.

Answer (score 4):

I think that a `return` in a `void` function is useless.

Also,

```
if (failure == true)
     return false;
   return true;
```

Could be rewritten as

```
return !failure;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your personal preferences, or if you're contributing to a group effort, the group's common coding style.

In some languages, a function implicitly returns the value of its last expression, so explicitly returning nothing can improve encapsulation.  JavaScript is not such a language, therefore my personal preference is against useless `return`s.  But I won't flame you if you do otherwise in your own project.

Answer (score 0):

**No**. "As a matter of best practice" you shouldn't blindly add a `return` statement to all functions. Just like you wouldn't declare useless variables in every function.

No `return` statement, `return;`, `return undefined;` all have the same outcome: the function will return `undefined`.